# Gradle multiproject doesn't add projects to classpath

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have some projects that depend on others. I also have a project that depends on two projects that each one depends on the same project. Something like this:

```
-Project A
 * Project 1
  ** Project C
 * Project 2
  ** Project C
```

And the structure of the workspace is like this:

```
-ProjectA
-ProjectC
-Project1
-Project2
```

All the projects are at the same level.

So in the settings.gradle in my Project A I have:

```
include ':Project1',':Project1:ProjectC',[...]
project(':Project1') = new File('../Project1')
project(':Project2') = new File('../Project2')
project(':Project1:ProjectC') = new File('../ProjectC')
project(':Project2:ProjectC') = new File('../ProjectC')
```

And in the build.gradle I do:

```
dependencies{ compile project('Project1'),project('Project2')
```

The problem is that it is not correctly added to the classpath. I think since both Project1 and Project2 depends on ProjectC it is overwritten somehow. Any ideas?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here is the tree of dependencies:

```
Root project 'ProjectA'
+--- Project ':ProjectB'
|    \--- Project ':ProjectB:Project1'
|         +--- Project ':ProjectB:Project1:Project2'
|         \--- Project ':ProjectB:Project1:Project3'
\--- Project ':ProjectC'
     \--- Project ':ProjectC:Project1'
          +--- Project ':ProjectC:Project1:Project2'
          \--- Project ':ProjectC:Project1:Project3'
```

Comment: If projectC exists in 1 location, you shouldn't be adding it twice to settings.gradle. Instead Project1 and Project2 should mention projectC in their respective dependencies sections.

Comment: Project1 and Project2 do mention ProjectC in their respective dependencies. But if I mention in Project A either Project1 or Project 2 gradle tells me that he cannot find Project1:ProjectC . I'm forced to add it, if I add a Project apparently I must add a reference to the projects which he depends.

Comment: I added some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did is change in the classpath the paths that where wrong like this:

build.gradle

```
 eclipse{
    classpath{
        file{
             whenMerged { classpath ->

                classpath.entries.find { entry -> 
                    entry.kind == 'src' && entry.path.contains('ProjectC')
                }.each{ entry ->
                    entry.path=file("/ProjectC")
                }



            }
        }
    }
 }
```

And it works fine. I still don't know why gradle doesn't make the classpath correctly...

Answer (score 1):

For a workspace that looks like this:

```
rootFolder
|
|- build.gradle 
|- settings.gradle 
|
|- ProjectA
|  |-build.gradle
|
|- Project1
|  |-build.gradle
|
|- Project2
|  |-build.gradle
|
|- ProjectC
   |-build.gradle
```

Your settings.gradle should look like this (irrespective of dependency relationships of the sub projects):

```
include ':ProjectA',':Project1',':Project2',':ProjectC',
```

You're just telling the root project that there are 4 subprojects and where they are located. That's it.

Now the dependency relationships are handled inside each subproject's build.gradle files. For a dependency relationship that looks like this:

```
ProjectA
|-Project1
|  |-ProjectC
|
|-Project2
   |-ProjectC
```

ProjectA's build.gradle:

```
dependencies{
    compile project(':Project1')
    compile project(':Project2')
}
```

Project1's build.gradle:

```
dependencies{
    compile project(':ProjectC')
}
```

Project2's build.gradle:

```
dependencies{
    compile project(':ProjectC')
}
```

Comment: The thing is that all the projects are at the same level. So  ProjectA settings.gradle must make reference to :Project1:ProjectC , right?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you use a root level settings.gradle as I've shown. It just keep things simpler.

Comment: To do it your way though, the reference to projectC would look exactly the same as you have it for project1. `include '../ProjectC'` and only once.

Comment: But ProjectA does not depend on ProjectC. It depends on both Project1 and Project2 which both depend on ProjectC. So in ProjectA I must mention Project1 and Project2 and the projects which these two depend on,right?
I'm sorry is so confusing, thank you for your help RaGe!

Comment: settings.gradle does **not** define dependency relationship. It is just a list of subprojects are and where they are located. Dependency information is contained in each project's build.gradle.

Comment: That does not work @RaGe. All the projects are at the same level. The thing is that some projects depend on others like the structure I posted but are at the same level. The thing is, in gradle, if a project depends on another which depends on another, I must reference like:  `include ':Project:Other' `

Comment: I added the tree of dependencies to the original post.